I need to update Element in Array in mongoDb
I have document with this structure . I need to change the Number 3 ,Pending --> Done
is there an possible ways of doing that?
db.Queue.find({"dr-name":"1guna"},{ "queue.0":1 })

doesn't return any thing
{   _id: ObjectId('6623b76f360aa86eb3560898'),   queue: [     [],     [],     [],     [],     []   ] }

[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6623b76f360aa86eb3560898"
  },
  "dr-name": "1guna",
  "live-number": "0",
  "est-number": "17",
  "queue": [
    [
      "1",
      "Banduka_Chamaras",
      "07:16:43",
      "pending",
      "1711111919"
    ],
    [
      "2",
      "chicken_Chamaras",
      "07:17:57",
      "pending",
      "0711111116"
    ],
    [
      "3",
      "butter_Chamaras",
      "07:29:11",
      "pending",
      "0711111516"
    ],
    [
      "4",
      "kaslisda_sds",
      "06:33:47",
      "pending",
      "5433454534"
    ],
    [
      "5",
      "kaslisda_sds",
      "07:13:42",
      "pending",
      "5433454539"
    ]
  ]
}]



Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Having the queue as an array-of-arrays instead of array-of-objects is a really bad schema. Especially when each item in the sub-array is a different field: ["1", "Banduka_Chamaras", "07:16:43", "pending", "1711111919"]. It should be an object with fields like: { id: "1", name: "Banduka_Chamaras", time: "07:16:43", status: "pending", code: "1711111919" }

I change the Structure

use pymongo
pip install pymongo

sample code for updating elements:
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Connect to the MongoDB database server (change 'localhost' and '27017' as necessary)
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')

# Connect to the specific database and collection
db = client['your_database_name']  # Replace 'your_database_name' with the name of your database
collection = db['Queue']

# Query to find the document
query = {"dr-name": "1guna", "queue.2.0": "3"}

# Update statement to change the status
update = {"$set": {"queue.2.3": "Done"}}

# Perform the update
result = collection.update_one(query, update)

# Output the result of the update
print("Documents updated:", result.modified_count)

# Close the connection
client.close()

UPDATE:
Update an element with mongodb:
db.Queue.updateOne(
  { "_id": ObjectId("6623b76f360aa86eb3560898"), "dr-name": "1guna" },
  { $set: { "queue.2.3": "Done" } }
)


The index of an array key is determined by the query on it. Therefore the array key must be included in the query. Please see the below examples.
test> db.test.drop();
test> db.test.insertOne({_id:1,a:[[1],[2],[3]]});
test> db.test.find();
[
  { _id: 1, a: [ [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ] ] }
]

// the query { "a":[3] } matches and therefore prints the element at the
// index 2
test> db.test.find({_id:1,"a":[3]},{"a.$":1});
[
  { _id: 1, a: [ [ 3 ] ] }
]

// the query { "a":[4] } does not match and therefore it does not print 
// the element 
db.test.find({_id:1,"a":[4]},{"a.$":1});
//no output

// this will thrown an error since the query does not include the array 
// key in projection, therefore the positional operator $ errors.
test> db.test.find({_id:1},{"a.$":1});
//MongoServerError: Executor error during find command :: caused by :: 
//positional operator '.$' couldn't find a matching element in the array
   
// Again the array key is not in the query, therefore it will not find 
// the item at 0th index, as a result no match will print 
test> db.test.find({_id:1},{"a.0":1});
[ { _id: 1, a: [ [], [], [] ] } ]

